# Halachos of a gastropub?

Tags: halacha, liquor-beer, marit-ayin, restaurant

BSD

Is it permitted to enter and drink at a gastropub (or restaurant/bar). Assuming the drinks (beer/whiskey) [are kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28951/can-one-trust-the-kashrut-of-alcoholic-beverages-in-bars) and this applies only in regards to someone who holds by the Shach (that one is permitted to drink barley products amongst non-Jews as per an interpretation of the Rema.)

My question stems from the ruling that it is forbidden to enter a treif restaurant unless in extenuating circumstances (maris ayin). However a bar as seen above is a little more lenient. So what happens when you combine the two?

Comment: What would be the problem if it's kosher?

Comment: @Scimonster see here problem of aris ayin and socializing with non jews. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/can-you-drink-a-beer-such-as-miller-or-budweiser-at-a-bar

Comment: Well then, i don't really see the difference between the questions. Is it because here there's also food?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22622/what-does-r-feinstein-say-about-eating-kosher-food-in-a-non-kosher-restaurant

Comment: very closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/what-defines-a-non-kosher-restaurant-for-purposes-of-maarit-ayin

Comment: I actually think this may specific case of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/what-defines-a-non-kosher-restaurant-for-purposes-of-maarit-ayin  - Is there a distinction?

Comment: A bar is more lenient??? Adderabba! Someone entering a bar is maris ayin for all sorts of bad things even if Kashrut isn't one of them

Answer (score 3):

[As discussed elsewhere](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/what-defines-a-non-kosher-restaurant-for-purposes-of-maarit-ayin), Rabbi Heinemann's opinion is that it's a problem if it's mainly known for the non-kosher stuff.

Do a reasonable amount of people go in there for just beer? If so, you should be okay.